# Convert json array to int array in Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json.net

I get a json file from a server in my Unity script. The json file looks like this.

```
{
  "drones": [
    [
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      1.0,
      0.0,      
    ],
    [
      0.0,
      0.0,
      1.0,
      1.0,
      0.0,
      
    ],
    [
      0.0,
      0.0,
      1.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      
    ]]
}
```

My method reads the data stream and converts it to a json format

```c#
 String incoming_data = reader.ReadLine();
 if(incoming_data != null)
 {
      JObject json = JObject.Parse(incoming_data);
 }
```

But now I want to store the values ​​of "drones" in a 2D int array. How would I do that?

Is there already a parser that can convert the values? Or am I already using JObject.Parse(incoming_data) incorrectly?

Comment: Note that 2D array (`[,]`) != Array of arrays (`[][]`) .. afaik JSON only supports `[][]` in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just  deserialize after parsing

```
int[][] drones= JObject.Parse(incoming_data)["drones"].ToObject<int[][]>();
```

Answer (score -1):

In your json object your `drones` is a JArray of JArray of int. That means you can make it an int array thus:

```cs
var intArray = json["drones"].ToObject<int[][]>();
```

Comment: Serge beat me to it ;-)